# Gnuplot: ramdom but deterministic color palette

Tags: gnuplot, diagram, random-seed, color-palette

I generate a histogram `columnstacked` as a stacked bar chart (see data and code below). The auto-generated diagram looks great, but the colors repeat too early (the first four colors appear twice):

[image: bar chart with repeating colors]

I'd like to use random colors, but determined/seeded by project ids so the colors don't change over time. I found how to set colors explicitly, but I would like to keep this as generic as possible. How to do that?

Data:

```
id,title,alice,bob,charly,diana,eleanor
foo1,Foo1 Project,,,,,
foo2,Foo2 Project,,22,,,
foo3,Foo3 Project,18,4,,10,
bar1,Bar One,,,4,4,15,
bar2,Bar Two,,,,2,
bar3,Bar Three,,,,,
baz1,First Baz,4,6,10,7,
baz3,Second Baz,,3,,,
baz3,Third Baz,2,,6,2,2,
quux1,Quux the 1st,4,6,6,1,
quux2,Quux the 2nd,,,8,,10,
quux3,Quux the 3rd,,,2,4,
```

Gnuplot code:

```
csvfile = 'wochenvorschau/alle.csv'
set datafile separator ','

set output 'output/persons.png'
set terminal png size 1000,600
set term png font "sans"

set style data histograms
set style histogram columnstacked
set style fill solid 0.7 noborder
set boxwidth 0.75
set xtics rotate by 90 right
set grid ytics linestyle 0

set key outside
set xlabel "Person"
set ylabel "Arbeitsstunden"
set timestamp "Stand: %d.%m.%Y %H:%M" bottom

stats csvfile using 0 nooutput
colmax = STATS_columns
rowmax = STATS_records

plot  for [COL=3:colmax] csvfile using COL title columnhead, \
      for [ROW=1:rowmax-1] '' every ::ROW::ROW using (t=strcol(2),NaN) with boxes lc ROW title t
```

Comment: What would be the maximum number of different colors/projects? Why do you want to have "random" colors? I would say in a graph it is important that the different colors are well distinguishable from each other. Maybe even for color-blind viewers (check `help colorsequence` option `podo`).

Comment: Do you really want **random** colours (but repeatable) or would deterministic ones based on the row number not be adequate - effectively converting the bitwise representation of ROW into RGB colours. Or alternatively set a default table up long enough to cover most use cases. I have **never** run out of colours for lines in Gnuplot but I have run out of monochrome linetypes which repeat much sooner. Too much data on one plot makes it impossible to understand!

Comment: Check this for color-blindness: https://mk.bcgsc.ca/colorblind/palettes.mhtml And does this maybe answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72741470/7295599

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! That's right, I don't want random colors, but usable ones and I don't want to define them by hand, if possible. I'll check out your pointers.

Comment: @memowe check also [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).  Maybe you can define a function which "runs around" on and in the HSL bicone mentioned in the article to create an "infinite" sequence of colors via a "simple" function. But I would agree with MartinBrown, it's probably easier to define a long enough sequence of colors and take the colors from there. You have to do this only once.